# ObjCMongoDB authentication

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mongodb, mongohq, objcmongodb

I'm very new to use ObjCMongoDB; I need to connect to a mongoDB from inside my application so I'm trying to integrate ObjCMongoDB.framework into my project.

I've read the wiki and I didn't find any reference on connecting to a DB with username and password. Maybe I didn't look into enough but the only suggested example of connection is the following:

```
MongoConnection *dbConn = [MongoConnection connectionForServer:@"127.0.0.1" error:&error];
```

with no user and no pwd.

Did anyone get into the same problem or is there a method that could be useful?
I found that in mongo.c there is `mongo_cmd_authenticate` but I don't know how to use it.

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: I don't think mongo has built in support for authentication. What are you really trying to do? Securely connect to a database on an external server?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to connect to an external server. In particula the hosting server is mongohq. I saw there that several languages like python, ruby, c# are supported. but not obj-c.

Comment: Did you see [this pull request](https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB/pull/4)?

Comment: I'm seeing just now, but it looks like not coming to a positive result.

Comment: Thank you. Integrating the patch works for connection. But after connecting successfully with authentication I got the following error when I tried to create a collection: MONGO_WRITE_ERROR: Write with given write_concern returned an error

Answer (score 1):

As of [this pull request](https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB/pull/4) the driver has support for authentication.

```
NSError *error = nil;

[connection authenticate:@"mydb" username:@"user" password:@"password" error:&error];
```